# Calling Extension Method to new Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and even newer to Extension Methods.

I have an extension Method I wrote

```
public static string ExtensionMethod(this Extension extype)
    {
        switch (extype)
        {
            case Extension.ONE:
                return "Object one string";

            case Extension.TWO:
                return "Object two string ";

            case Extension.THREE:
                return "Object three string";

            default:
                return "Any other string";
        }
    }
```

So basically what this does is compare selections that have been made in the view and changes the label to match what they selected.  Easy Peasy.
Now they want their reciept to reflect that exact string. So I have a class that manages my e-mails but I can't figure out how to put the value in the class.

in my view I call

```
@Model.ViewModelReference.Extension();
```

this brings it in great, but I have no idea how to reference an extension class in another class

```
email.To = receiptInfo.EmailAddress;
email.From = "email address";
email.Subject = "Reciept";
            var bodyFormat = new StringBuilder();
            bodyFormat.AppendLine("*RECEIPT*\t");
            bodyFormat.AppendLine("I want Object string to show up here");
```

**EDIT**

Thank you.  I implemented it like this

```
bodyFormat.AppendLine(MyNameSpace.MyExtension.Extension());
```

but I am getting an argument error, and I am not 100% sure which argument I should put in it, or it it even needs one.  If I don't add the () it throws a cannot convert to string error. through logic I put in extype but it doesn't like that either, says it doesn't exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to include the class that the extension method is in and the extension method will be available.

In you class that manages e-mails add:

```
using MyNameSpace.MyExtension;
```

Then to use it, just have something of type `Extension` and call `ExtensionMethod()` off of it. So it would look something like:

```
using MyNameSpace.MyExtension;

var myExtension = new Extension();
myExtension.ExtensionMethod()
```

You cannot simply call `MyNameSpace.MyExtension.Extension()`, you need an instance of `MyExtension`, which is why in my example I have `myExtension` variable.

Comment: Thank you.  I implemented it like this bodyFormat.AppendLine(MyNameSpace.MyExtension.Extension()); but I am getting an argument error, and I am not 100% sure which argument I should put in it, or it it even needs one.  If I don't add the () it throws a cannot convert to string error.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to call the extension method

Comment: This worked amazingly, thank you for the lesson. I REALLY appreciate it.  All my education is front end so learning MVC and all the backend coding has been quite the brain stretch ^.^